# Inserting multiple values into a database

Tags: python, sql

I wrote a method to add a single employee to a database:

```
def insert_employee(emp):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('employees.db')
    curs = conn.cursor()
    with conn:
        curs.execute("INSERT INTO employees VALUES (:first, :last, :pay)",
                     {'first': emp.first, 'last': emp.last, 'pay': emp.pay})
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

This works:

```
emp1 = Employee("Josh", "Brandon", "2000")
DataBase.insert_employee(emp1)
```

I, then, expanded it to add a list of employees:

```
def insert_employees(emp_list):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('employees.db')
    curs = conn.cursor()
    with conn:
        for i in range(2):
            curs.execute("INSERT INTO employees VALUES (:first, :last, :pay)",
                         {'first': emp_list[i].first, 'last': emp_list[i].last, 'pay': emp_list[i].pay})
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

This does not work:

```
emps = [("Brenda", "Johnson", "4000"), ("Reza", "Amir", "5000")]
DataBase.insert_employees(emps)
```

I get an `AttributeError` that says `'tuple' object has no attribute 'first'`.

What am I missing or doing werong?

Comment: if i read this correctly, your  "Employee" is a class with attribute "first" but emps is just a list of tuples. you would need to create an instance of the Employee class from each of these tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a list of tuples. It seems like you meant to have a list of employee objects, to do so change

```
emps = [("Brenda", "Johnson", "4000"), ("Reza", "Amir", "5000")]
```

to

```
emps = [Employee("Brenda", "Johnson", "4000"), Employee("Reza", "Amir", "5000")]
```

Answer (score 1):

This creates an instance of a class, you used it´s getter functions like first, last, etc.

```
emp1 = Employee("Josh", "Brandon", "2000")
```

But this is just an array

```
emps = [("Brenda", "Johnson", "4000"), ("Reza", "Amir", "5000")]
```

Depending on how you get your data and how much you want to mutate it, you could just access the keys

`emp_list[i][0]` instead of first

`emp_list[i][1]` instead of last

Answer (score 1):

`emp_list[i]` returns a tuple and naturally it doesn't have any of attributes you are looking for.

If you want to get values by attributes, you could look at [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

```
employee = namedtuple('Employee', ['first', 'last', 'pay'])
emps = [employee('John', 'Wick', '1000000'), ...)
insert_emploees(emps)
```

But a simpler solution would be just to handle your tuples better:

```
curs.execute("INSERT INTO employees VALUES (:first, :last, :pay)",
              dict(zip(['first', 'last', 'pay'], *i)))
```